# What happens when I overload an induction generator

Tags: generator, induction, power-generation

I am trying to generate power with a small induction generator.

The RPM is constant.
What will hapen when the rated input torque is exceeded?

Comment: some bad smell appears unless protected\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot maintain constant RPM with an induction machine. More torque means more RPM.

Two things may happen:

- you may burn the generator
- if you push really hard you may slip over pushover torque and the generator will run away (see the torque-speed curve below; image from [here](https://circuitglobe.com/induction-generator.html))

[image: Induction motor torque-speed curve]

Comment: He's talking about a generator; not a motor.

Comment: @Andyaka it doesn't matter. Unless the question is about doubly fed induction generator, but it is not indicated.